# FPDF CoreFonts issue in TYPO3 Controller

Tags: php, typo3, fpdf

I'm running a script which generates a PDF via FPDF. In "standalone" it works like a charm, but when I copy the same script inside a T3 custom action, it throws an error.

```
in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in ...bla/fpdf.php line 527
```

fpdf.php line 527:

```
if(in_array($family,$this->CoreFonts))
```

CoreFonts is definded in line 117

```
$this->CoreFonts = array('courier', 'helvetica', 'times', 'symbol', 'zapfdingbats');
```

Sure, I added the namespaces and stuff. I think it lies somewhere at the CoreFonts-array.

How to fix this?
I'm also using only one font for a simple PDF, so maybe we can turn this 'look for font'-thingy off?

[Here the full fpdf.php](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f13856542915688d60fedb3b0bb85ba4ffbde6af)

Comment: Please add the full code. It could be that it gets unset, or that `$this` is pointing to something you don't think it does.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes it's just the code of the fpdf.php file, I didn't change anything

Comment: Ah, I see. I misread the question. Still, it's nice to be able to see the code without having to do a Google search, and it'll make people more willing to answer.

Comment: Thanks but it's about 1800 lines, I thought nobody would want to read it. I'll post it now.

Comment: 1800 lines isn't much, especially since you pinpoint the line of the error. (Also, being me, I forgot to mention that how you use it is also important) Still, since you found the answer, no biggy

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer was somewhere else.

Leaving everything like it is and creating a class with `$pdf = new FPDF();` would result in an error because the class couldn't be found.

I'm quite new to PHP and I saw something with namespaces inside the error-message, so I added the namespace into the `fpdf.php` file.
Now the class could be found, but there was the problem which is described above.
Actually it's described wrongly, the problem was, that the `$this` variable was permanently `NULL`.

Well, it was almost as hard like Dark Souls 2, but I finally got the solution:

Instead of `$pdf = new FPDF();`
use `$pdf = new \FPDF();`

It has something to do with namespaces, again.

I thought I'd post my answer **for newbies like me who want to use a TYPO3 custom action to create PDFs inside an extension.**